# Python Inheritance - TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given

Tags: python, inheritance, python-requests

```
import requests
class Poll(requests.session()):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

with Poll() as p:
# do stuff

>>TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given
```

I don't understand why an error is being thrown. Doesn't *args take care of any extra positional arguments?

Comment: This code defines a class, but doesn't actually create any objects of that class.  Show us that code also.

Comment: And the class declaration seems odd: `class Poll(requests.session())` -- Do you mean `Poll` to inherit from the type that is _returned_ by calling `requests.session()`?

Comment: Edited. I just use a with statement.

When I call the session object normally, I use "with requests.session() as s:". requests.session is a function that, when called, creates a session object.

Comment: What `Poll()` is doing is calling the init on `requests.session()` because you're not calling super on the `session`, but the object the `session` returns. (In other words, subclass the class `requests.session`, not the object `requests.session()`)

Comment: Ohh. Am I inheriting from an instance of the class instead of the class itself?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's the problem.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds with that change, I get a new error: "TypeError: function() argument 1 must be code, not str"

Comment: However if you want to use context managers, it's best to use `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods to return the session object. What four arguments are you sending in?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. requests.session is a *function* that returns an instance of the *class* requests.Session.

Fixed code:

```
import requests
class Poll(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
```

Comment: @DavisHerring: Indeed.  Daniel, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/100003/1340389 for the difference.